# Using Variables with Regex that contain a space (\s) and sed

Tags: regex, bash, variables, sed

Im trying to create a sort script using literal string variables and Regex and a sort using sed in bash. I cannot seem to find the liternal strings with spaces when using variables, although can find them when using the regex directly. So :

```
#!/bin/bash
group1="IRISHFHD"
group2="REGIONAL FHD"

sed -i '/group-title="'${group1}/',+1d' JWLINE.m3u
sed -i '/group-title="'${group2}/',+1d' JWLINE.m3u
```

Ive tried adding \s into the group variable but it doesnt work.

John

Comment: Do you really want a literal single dbl-quote (unmatched pair) in your match string? Good luck.

Comment: Looking for `sed -i '/group-title="'"$group2"'/,+1d' JWLINE.m3u`?

Comment: Why is what im doing very strange? Regex is new to me.

Comment: To expand on @shellter's comment:  you are matching /group-title="IRISHFHD.  Maybe you should match /group-title="IRISHFHD" (note the closing double-quote)?  You would write  sed -i '/group-title="'"${group1}"'/,+1d' JWLINE.m3u (I have also added double-quotes around the shell variable ${group1}, as suggested in the answer from Gordon Davisson - needed to protect the space in one of the shell variables values - as explained by Gordon).  Seems like a tough way to approach sorting, though.  If you could arrange to put each element on one line, then you could sort lines with the sort(1) utility.

Answer (score 2):

The problem has nothing to do with regex, it's all down to how the shell treats variables' values. When a variable is expanded without double-quotes around it (i.e. `${group2}`), the shell will split it into "words" based on whitespace. It'll also try to expand any words that contain shell wildcards into lists of matching files, and several regex metacharacters look like shell wildcards, which can cause serious chaos.

In this example:

```
sed -i '/group-title="'${group2}/',+1d' JWLINE.m3u
```

It's a little more complicated, because the variable reference is in between two single-quoted sections. In this case, the part before the variable reference gets attached to the first "word" in the variable, and the part after gets attached to the last word. Essentially, it expands into the equivalent of this:

```
sed -i '/group-title="REGIONAL' 'FHD/,+1d' JWLINE.m3u
                               ^ That's a space between arguments
```

Anyway, since it gets split on the whitespace, `sed` gets two partial arguments instead of one whole one, and it doesn't work at all.

Solution: as in almost all situations, you should have double-quotes around the variable reference to prevent weird effects like this. There are a few options for this. You could just add double-quotes around the variable part:

```
sed -i '/group-title="'"${group2}"/',+1d' JWLINE.m3u
```

...but IMO this is confusing; some of those quotes are syntactic (i.e. parsed by the shell), and one is literal (passed to `sed` as part of the regex), and it's not obvious which are which. I'd prefer to just use double-quotes around the whole thing, and escape the double-quote that's supposed to be literal:

```
sed -i "/group-title=\"${group2}/,+1d" JWLINE.m3u
                     ^^ Escape makes this " a literal part of the argument.
```

(In double-quotes, you'd also need to escape any dollar signs, backslashes, or backticks that were supposed to be literal parts of the argument. But in this case, there aren't any of those.)

Comment: What is the contents of `JWLINE.m3u`? Also, which `sed` are you using? Different versions (e.g. GNU vs bsd) behave a bit differently (e.g. the GNU version recognizes `\s` as a shorthand for `[[:space:]]`, but bsd one doesn't; bshd requires a file extension argument after `-i` (or `''` for no backup), but GNU doesn't; etc). Also, try putting `set -x` before the troublesome command (and `set +x after it), and the shell will print the equivalent of the post-expansion command, which may clarify what's happening.

Comment: Sorry Gordon, my bad. Your suggestion in fact worked perfectly. Thanks for the help.

Comment: As an aside, couldn't this be done in a single execution? `sed -i "/group-title=\"${group1}/,+1d; /group-title=\"${group2}/,+1d" JWLINE.m3u`